# Check if certain value exist in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to display a div conditionaly based on if a value exists in localStorage:

So here is an example the values present in localstorage for the key "elementor":

Key = elementor

Value = `{__expiration: {}, pageViews: 2, popup_times: 1, popup_disable: true}`

How to write a conditional to check if `popup_disable: true` is present or not?

Thanks!

Comment: unclear how that code is working. how is that being returned from localstroage. Show real code.

Comment: That is not a code, that is the value stored in localstorage.

Comment: did you try `if(Value.popup_disable){ ... ` ?

Comment: Here is a screenshot https://i.ibb.co/N9fGQWY/Desktop-screenshot-2.png

Comment: I know that is not code, show code on how you are reading the local strorage. Not sure how you are going to parse it out if that is the actual string since it is not valid JSON.

Comment: Tried but does not work!

Comment: so use getItem, JSON.parse, and read the property. Show what you tried. If you showed what you tried, you would have had an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would with any other object.

local_storage_value = localStorage.getItem(key)

```
if (local_storage_value.popup_disable) {
...
}
```

This checks if popup_disable is set to true, but doesn't check if the key exists in your localstorage.

```
if("popup_disable" in local_storage_value){
...
}
```

This checks if the key is present.

Comment: So tried like this

```if ("popup_204921_disable" in local_storage_value) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}```

But no luck 

The only thing that works is if checking for the key like this:

```if ("elementor" in localStorage) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}```

Comment: why are you looking for "popup_204921_disable" when your question asks how to check if popup_disable: true. Please edit your question to clearly define what your exact problem is

Comment: The popup will add "popup_204921_disable: true" if the pop up has been closed. If the pop up has not been closed then "popup_204921_disable" will not exist in the local storage. I am not sure that "popup_204921_disable" is key!! As mentioned above the key is "elementor" Please check the screensbhot i posted above https://i.ibb.co/N9fGQWY/Desktop-screenshot-2.png. So i am trying to check if the user closed the popup and thus has "popup_204921_disable: true" value in there localstorage, if not not closed then they would not.

Comment: Miro, how can we help if you do not even know the name of the key? What key are you talking about? For the local storage or for the object?

Comment: For the object. Looking if "popup_204921_disable" is present will do the job.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. If you just want to check if the key exists, then you can use my 2nd example.

Comment: Yes and i get nothing fired doing that!

Comment: Why don't you actually edit your question & provide your exact code

Comment: So here is the code trying based on your answer:

`var local_storage_value = localStorage.getItem(elementor)

if("popup_204921_disable" in local_storage_value){
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}`

Comment: Miro, you just said your key is popup_204921_disable... instead of copy and pasting blindly, did you try and replace "popup_disable" with your actual key?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, can you show us what is inside local_storage_value

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: What are the contents of local_storage_value once you retrieve your items from local storage

Comment: My understanding regardless if the key/value is correct the alert should fire yes or no. But with your code nothig fires!

Comment: {__expiration: {}, pageViews: 4, popup_204921_times: 1, popup_204921_disable: true, popup_118_times: 1}
pageViews: 4
popup_118_times: 1
popup_204921_disable: true
popup_204921_times: 1
__expiration: {}

Comment: If nothing is firing then there is something wrong with your code. My code is just a 1 line snippet, so there is something else going on. You can try: local_storage_values.hasOwnProperty('popup')

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for making me look stupid @alex067 and @epascarello... but most your questions/answers did not make sense!

Obviously am not expert on this thus am here but I figured it out and super simple. So just had to JSON.parse the key and then look for if the popup_disable is in the value like this:

```
var popupDisable = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('elementor'));

if(popupDisable.hasOwnProperty('popup_disable')){ 
alert('yes'); 
} else { 
alert('no'); 
}
```